# Не запускается код C# в visual studio code

Tags: c#

Не запускается код в студии. Пытался запускать f5 и cntrl + f5 выдавал ошибки 1. launch: launch.json must be configured. change program to the path и 2. the prelaunchtask build terminated with exit code 1. Переустанавливал студию не помогло, так же гуглил эти проблемы безуспешно. Несколько дней не получается решить проблему, от отчаяния прошу помощи у вас, мудрейших. Сейчас при запуске кода дают выбор дебагера [image: вот]

Comment: у вас код не рабочий, он не будет компилироваться, а когда поправите, выбирайте первый пункт .NET 5+ and .NET Core и все

Comment: Code для обучения, не лучшая идея, ибо вам нужен помощник, который будет помогать вам в случае проблем, подсказывает как их решить, что можно сделать, а что нельзя. Code - это блокнот, не более того, он капризен, он нестабилен, он многое не прощает, он вас только запутает. Поэтому советую вам для начала, всеж установить полноценную студию и использовать ее. Ну а касательно ошибки, вам пишет "файл launch.json должен быть настроен", в этом файле прописывается то, как Code должен компилировать и запускать ваш код, на скрине первый пункт обычно делает базовую настройку за вас, но не всегда верно.

Comment: Жмёте `Ctrl+Shift+P` (или меню View > Command Palette), в строку поиска вбиваете `.net`, выбираете пункт `.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug`

Comment: Ставьте Visual Studio 2022